# Get all binary looking numbers(1,10,11,100 etc) from 0 to 10000 in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to print all binary looking numbers like `0,1,10,11..etc` from 1 to n. Can one help me way around here. I am looking for answer **without the use of Regex in any case**

Comment: Now, you've a tool for the tasks like this, why is it forbidden to use it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Checking whether a string is constituted of only ones and zeroes is absolutely possible without regexps (though they'd be the easiest way to do that).

Comment: Do it the other way, get all four-bit binary strings and parse them to integers. That's likely to be more efficient than filtering all 10,000 values for the 16 you care about.

Comment: @Teemu Actually I solved problem using regex but problem has this condition of solving it without regex so can't help much on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's the best way to solve your problem but can try out this function:

```
function getBinariesUpTo(min, max) {
    const binariesList = [];
    for (let i = min ; i < max; i++) {
        const iStringified = i.toString();
        if (iStringified === parseInt(iStringified, 2).toString(2)) {
            binariesList.push(i);
        }
    }
    return binariesList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kir, It does solves the problem and so far best approach.